Apache reads only the first line of .htaccess
I have a .htaccess file with text
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex default.html

The problem is that when the site loads, default.html is not loaded, and when I tried to write like this:
DirectoryIndex default.html
RewriteEngine On

Then the site began to load, but all subsequent rules did not. Moreover, even if the first line is a comment, the subsequent ones are also not loaded. What can be done? Thanks in advance.

Any messages in the error logs? Might be related to Windwos/Unix Lineendings

@arch no, there are no errors in the logs. Could this be due to the fact that I am running Linux on proot?

What do you actually mean with "no errors in the logs"? Sure you are looking at the right log file? There always are entries in the log file, otherwise it does not work.

By default, apache uses at elast two log files (access and error). Then there are also systemd logs.

The error was in the encoding. Unix uses a line break of the form \n, while MacOS uses \r, which is why only the first line was read. The solution is to simply copy the contents of the file, recreate it and paste it back with the required encoding.
